# Diophantine Equation $ x^n + y^n =z^n (x<y, n>2) $

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, perfect-powers

I am looking for simple college level algebraic solution to prove that $x$ and $y$ ($x$ < $y$) for the above equation can't be prime numbers. (I know more complex and involved solution using high level of mathematics exists).

That $y$ can't be a prime number can be shown. But can it be shown for $x$ also ? I know it can be shown for $x$ if we can show, by some simple method, that the following is always false. $$ x^n + y^n =(1+y)^n$$ Can anyone provide me some hints or refer to any online resource. The emphasis is on simple college level algebra.

I have proved the first part ( $y$ can't be prime ) in the following way:

$$y^n = (z-x)(z^{n-1}+...+x^{n-1})$$
This makes $(z-x)$ have two solutions $(z-x)=1$ or $(z-x)=y^r$ where $r \le n$. It can be easily shown that $z \ne x+1$. Also if $z-x=y^r$ then $x+y > z = x+ y^r$ . which makes $y> y^r$ which is contradictory.
However  as $x<y$ the same is not applicable for $x$. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: I don't suppose "by Fermat's Last Theorem" is an acceptable response?

Comment: @Barry - can we say that the proof of FLT is simple college level algebra ?

Answer (score 1):

As a corollary of [Zsigmondy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem), if $n>2$ and $a,b$ are positive coprime integers, then $a^n-b^n$ has a prime divisor that does not divide $a-b$. Consequently, if  $(x,y,z)$ is a coprime solution to $x^n+y^n=z^n$ ($n>2$) then $z^n-x^n$ and $z^n-y^n$ each have at least two distinct prime divisors. Thus $x$ and $y$ cannot be prime.

Comment: How is $2^6-1^6$ an exception?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen edited.

Comment: All significant enough mathematical property  is called theorem and whether this is associated with an author's name, this theorem is difficult to obtain for the first time. Hence,  impossible for Barun been able to resolve this problem but it is noteworthy his good sense to ask questions.

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez I can't see what you want to say, but we can continue this is chat, if you wish.

Comment: @Barto: I have no chat and traductor of Google is not 100% efficient. What I wanted to say is that many things are quite difficult without using a theorem and quite immediate using it. What I mean in any way is to use a theorem is not valid; quite the opposite. Best regards.

Comment: I see. (You can talk Spanish to me, if you want, though my Spanish is not that good yet.) Although Zsigmondy's theorem has some elementary proofs I understand that some find it overpowered. I'll see if there's a way using the (much more elementary) Lifting The Exponent lemma; I guess there is.

Comment: @Barto : A little more elaboration will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I understand, Barun, what you are looking for is a proof to a fact of elementary level like, say, “one of x, y, z, must be even” although less easy or maybe difficult but unpretentious. I try here to give you a proof for $n=5$ hoping  you will see the case $p=$ odd prime using this hint.

Recall that it is enough to consider n odd prime and $x, y, z$ coprimes. It is clear for you that if $z-y > 1$ then you finish. One has then being $x=q$ an odd prime (why not $x=2$?)
$q^5 = (y+1)^5 – y^5 = 5y^4+10y^3+10y^2+5y +1$ implies $q^5-1=5y^4+10y^3+10y^2+5y$
$q^5-1=5y^4+10y^3+10y^2+5y=5(y^4+y^3+y^2+y)$ 
 If $q=5$ then $-1≡0 (mod 5)$, absurde, therefore (Fermat's little theorem) $q-1 ≡0 (mod 5)$ and $q= 5m+1$.

Hence you have
$(5m+1)^5 = 5y^4+10y^3+10y^2+5y +1$;  this gives
$A^5 + 5(A-y)[A^3 + (y+2)A^2 + (y^2+2y+2)A + (y^3+2y^2+2y+1)] = 0$   where $A= 5m$ so
$5^4m^5 + (A-y)[A^3 + (y+2)A^2 + (y^2+2y+2)A + (y^3+2y^2+2y+1)] = 0$ therefore either
$5|(A-y)$  or $5|(y^3+2y^2+2y+1)$  (I leave you the job to see that the first is not possible).
Thus $ y^3+2y^2+2y+1 ≡0 (mod 5)$. This is  possible just for $y=5n-1$ because making $f(x) = y^3+2y^2+2y+1$ we have modulo 5, $(f(0), f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)) = (1, 1, 1,2,0)$. Hence you have the restriction $y=5n-1$.

I stop here. I wanted help you but the required job seems not easy. I do not remember seeing it on the big miscellany of partial conditions on FLT before Wiles & Company so do not rule out that your problem could be difficult enough . I wanted a proof for you but I could not.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try out your method too.